# Merge USB partitions into single partition on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb, partitioning, windows-8.1

I was trying to install Ubuntu in dual mode on my PC, but it failed and it divided my USB drive into three partitions whilst making USB a bootable device.

Now I want to merge these USB partitions into single partition. 
See the Disk Management display:

[image: Disk Management display]

You can see there are three partitions on one USB drive
(with sizes 1.43 GB, 2 MB, 450 MB).

When I right click on these partitions there is no option **Extend Volume** or **Delete Volume** or **Shrink Volume**. These options are disabled.

Please help me: how can I merge them to single partition?

Comment: "Unallocated" is not a partition; it's a lack of any. According to the screenshot the only partition on your USB drive is this small 2 MB one. Are you sure you cannot delete it? Removing its drive letter may be required first. I'm not really a Windows guy, just guessing; therefore a comment, not an answer.

Comment: You can use a tool such as BootIce (http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html) which will do the job in a simple and straightforward way.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows diskpart should be able to delete these.  It's a command line prompt you run as administrator.
You need to launch and elevated command prompt and run diskpart. See: https://commandwindows.com/diskpart.htm

In diskpart:

1. list disk  -- this shows all the disks
2. select disk *number*  to select the correct disk, probably disk 1
3. list partition  -- this shows all 3 of your partitions
4. select partition *number*  -- to select one of the partitions
5. delete partition  -- removes the partition

repeat steps 3,4,5 for the remaining partitions until all 3 have been removed.

**Be very careful when selecting and deleting, make sure you've got the right disk and partition before you delete.  If you select and delete the wrong partition you could lose your data**

some pics here: https://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/delete-partition-4125.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very **careful** by proceeding on *Disk Management* tool. Alternatively try third party free software

- [AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html)

Have used the Freeware version for a number of occasions, incl. partition, merge and resize etc. Quite user friendly, see their website [screenshot](https://www.disk-partition.com/features/merge-partitions.html).